# JPA Aggreate values return type and conversion to json , jax-rs 2.0

Tags: json, jpa, jax-rs, aggregate

In full column selection query like

> select e from Entity e

the result type is of Entity  and when aggregate functions used in query e.g in my code  below

```
@GET
@Path("/list")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

public Response getAverage() throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
     Timestamp startDate =Timestamp.valueOf("2016-11-15 14:12:17");
     Timestamp endDate =Timestamp.valueOf("2016-11-21 16:12:17");
     EntityManagerFactory emf =Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("NeoMetrics");
 EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
 Query q = em.createQuery("Select avg(e.uniqueCalls)  , avg(e.primaryCalls) , avg(e.secondaryCalls), "
        + "avg(e.backupCalls), avg(e.uniqueS1Calls),"
        + " avg(e.uniqueS2Calls) as s2calls, avg(e.uniqueS3Calls), avg(e.uniqueS4Calls)"
        + " from ESnapshot e where e.queueid = :id and e.sampleTS between :startDate and :endDate",ESnapshot.class);
 q.setParameter("id",2);
 q.setParameter("startDate",startDate);
 q.setParameter("endDate",endDate);

 Object[] es = (Object[]) q.getSingleResult();
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  String  json = mapper.writeValueAsString(es);
    return Response.ok(json).build();

}
```

the result is an object array and after changing it to string it become string array using object mapper , here is the output  . But what i really need is  proper json format with key and values,  the  column from table  as keys . any help will be really appreciated
[image]

Comment: Create an Object from the array. What's the difficulty? Also, JAX-RS serializes to JSON for you. No need to marshal to JSON by yourself. And certainly not by creating a new ObjectMapper every time. ObjectMapper is thread-safe and intended to be shared and reused.

Comment: @JBNizet the problem is not the conversion  , main problem is when i use aggregate function i get object array with only column value , so if i convert it to an object still i dont have key for it like in normal json we have , e.g  { "salary": "5000"} , i am only getting 5000 not salary .

Comment: You'll have the key once your array is transformed to an object, and this object is marshalled to JSON. The keys are the fields of that object.

Comment: @JBNizet can you give me an example  regarding the above code please

Comment: `class Foo { double uniqueCallsAvg; double primaryCallsAvg; // constructor and getters ommitted }` ... `Foo foo = new Foo((Double) array[0], (Double) array[1]);`... and return foo as the response body. That will serialize to `{ "uniqueCallsAvg": 5, "primaryCallsAvg": 5}`.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks a lot , really appreciate your comments